# Should a domain object wrap/contain a DTO interface?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, domain-model, repository

Using .NET - I have an interface IPerson.  This interface is implemented by classes in  multiple, separate repositories, e.g. EF6 (EfPerson), custom SQL (SqlPerson), or even custom assembly connecting to a web service (WebPerson).

Assuming rich domain model, my idea is that my lovely rich domain object 'Person' could have a private member variable _PersonDto of type IPerson, supplied via constructor.  The members of Person would be the only way to access data from the _PersonDto.

Q. Is there anything actually inherently wrong with that approach?  (Assume I'm not lazy loading, and that I will possibly have a service layer for cross-cutting stuff).

Please note I'm using DTO here to simply mean the anaemic objects I get back from my repositories.

Comment: See also [this post](http://cgeers.com/2009/03/14/data-access-objects-with-the-entity-framework/).  It describes the same thing, programming against data access object interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of observations.

First, classes (DTO or otherwise) should be data-persistence agnostic.  In other words, they should have no awareness of their underlying data persistence mechanism.  It worries me that you have three different versions of a Person that are distinguished only by the way they are stored or retrieved.

Second, DTO classes are merely containers, used primarily for movement of data from one place to another.  The only reason you might set them via constructor is if:

1. You wanted them to be immutable, or
2. You wanted them to be valid on instantiation.

Validation in business systems is normally accomplished elsewhere (it shouldn't necessarily be tied to the Person object, although you can annotate objects with validation information), and in business systems, there's generally no expectation of immutability (most business systems are a big mass of mutable data and business logic).

So for all these reasons, I say the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Surely my 3 different repositories can return 3 different classes, as long as they implement the abstraction - the IPerson interface?

Comment: Sure, but... Why?  The manner in which objects are saved or loaded has nothing to do with their individual characteristics.  That's the very definition of tight coupling.

Comment: So the various repositories should all return the same class - such as a persistence class (I'll stop calling it a DTO), and dispense with the interface?

Comment: I have the feeling that we're talking past each other.  I never said anything about a persistence class, nor did I mention interfaces.  I merely said that the DTO should not have any knowledge of how it is persisted, and that setting a DTO in the constructor is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right!  See my original question re my abuse of the term 'DTO' - 'Please note I'm using DTO here to simply mean the anaemic objects I get back from my repositories'

Comment: This post if probably closest to what I'm trying to describe: [link](http://thatsthaway.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/design-pattern-dao-pattern.html)

Comment: Validation elsewhere leads to anemic models.  While a subclass per data access probably isn't the way to go, neither is using an orm to map the domain model.  When it comes to data access, the choice is usually SRP vs. encapsulation.  Given that choice, I'll choose to keep encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the backing state DTO approach, in fact it's [recommended](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879) by some DDD people.

However, populating a domain object from heterogeneous sources is not the main reason for it. It's more about solving the entity encapsulation vs persistability paradox by having an object that is easily accessible and mappable by ORMs.

`EfPerson`/`SqlPerson`/`WebPerson` and the `IPerson` interface are unnecessary IMO, because the backing state object is just a dumb data bag that will contain exactly the same thing in all cases.

Data gathering and mapping logic should rather be placed in anticorruption layers between the various source systems and your own system, or in different concrete Repository implementations.

Comment: Thanks, good answer.  So my DTO should be a class, rather than an interface?  I found the interface approach quite useful thus far.

Comment: It should definitely be a class. The interface is useful when you have behavior and not just data, is it the case in your current implementation ?

Comment: ...and the reason it's useful so far, it enables my EF classes (for example) to retain their persistence-specific attributes (yeah I know I can move most/all of that into fluent API), and I just just abstract away via my IPerson (it's an IDto really) interface.  EF, SQL, Web (CRM), etc. are implementors of my IDtos, and this allows the shape of their implementation classes can be quite different.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't thinking about attributes. Seems legit to me then (except the name `IPerson` which sounds... awkward)

Comment: I think you should refrain from introducing methods in that interface and classes though, they are not supposed to do anything. Even if attributes can be hints for an external tool, hydrating themselves is not their job.

Comment: And I would definitely use fluent mapping over attributes if you can afford it, too.

Comment: Good question, re behaviour.  Yes there currently is, but I think I can refactor that out and be left with just the DTO class.  That would enable my domain Person class to retain access to its data after the backing store connection has closed.  That's a good thing, but downside is I'll need to track which store my Person belongs to so I can write back to it.  Persistence awareness?

Comment: I would first look for a business-related discriminator between those stores (e.g. all persons living in the US go in this store, others in that store) and let the application service call the correct repo based on that, but a more elegant solution would be to have domain events which the different data store adapters can listen to in order to decide if they'll persist to their store or not.

Comment: It gets more tricky if the provenance follows no rule -- then you might indeed have to reflect provenance in the DTO itself.